# Which is the best practice between implicit linking and explicit linking of DLL

Tags: c++, dll, sfml

I've seen there are many different reason to link a .DLL implicitly and explicitly. I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 and C++ with SFML.

Implicit:
-Good side:
   You have access to the .DLL header(.h) and know the function it's contain.
   It's easier to link and use.
   Less prone to do error.
   Seem to be the most common practice used.

-Bad side:
   Absolutely need  the .lib, .h and .dll file to link.
   Take more disk space due to more file.

Explicit:
-Good side:
   Take less disk space due to needing .dll only.

-Bad side:
   Prone to error due to possibility of using a function that the dll may not have and also by loading it correctly.
   No way to know the function the dll contain since you don't have the header.

1: I've heard that linking explicitly is kind of a bad practice. Is this correct?

2: Should I focus mainly on linking implicitly?

3: Obviously, my knowledge on DLL is minimal, is there more good and bad side I failed to see about implicit and explicit ways' to link a dll?

4: Since I plan on making game, is it a good practice to place the sprite-sheet into a dll to load the texture once with pointer?

Comment: You are getting this pretty wrong, really rather best to actually try this.  There is no difference in disk space, in both cases you only need to deploy the DLL.   Explicit needs *more* space on your dev machine, you can't bypass the need to declare the function pointer types and the code to dig out the export.  Very painful code that's hard to maintain, especially for a large library like SFML.  You only use explicit *because* the DLL might not have the export.  Never necessary for SFML because it is you that copies the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove your “take less disk space” point. The *.lib is only required on developer’s machine. In the installer, only the DLL is needed in both cases.

1. It depends on the use case. There are cases when explicit linking (usually called dynamic loading) is the only way, for example when those DLLs implement user-provided plugins.
2. For a game, or other desktop app targeted towards <s>kids</s> large audience of inexperienced users, I recommend not using DLLs at all. Link all the code statically. Not only it makes your app smaller (linker will throw out whatever code from those libraries you aren’t calling), this will also eliminate a class of bugs. This certainly applies to C runtime library (msvcrt.dll) as well.

_4. I wouldn’t do that. Logically, a sprite sheet is data, not code. You shouldn’t place it in DLLs regardless of how you load the DLL, statically or dynamically. Instead, load that data from a file. If you only need that data while loading your game or a level, use ReadFile API. If you read from that sprite sheet constantly while the game is running, you can map that complete data file to the address space of your process, see CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile API (internally, DLL loading uses this method). Just beware for 32-bit apps address space is scarce.